# Function for this 3D curve

Tags: graphing-functions

I am trying to plot a 3D surface like the picture below to help depict the relationship between some variables. I have been fiddling with Google Search builtin plotter, trying different equations, but I do not have the knowledge to progress in this issue. I could go on trying random combinations of operators, but I thought maybe you could help...

The 3D surface should be something like this:

[image]

This is as far as I have got: $\sqrt{\frac {1}{\cos x + \sin y}}$, but I am sure there is a better way!

Can I have your help? Thank you very much.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking what is the equation to the surface you have drawn?

Comment: Try $x + y + z + a (x y + y z + z x) = 1$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: Hi @Rise, yes, that's what I am asking. Rahul, I plotted your suggestion in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%2B+y+%2B+z+%2B+10%28xy+%2B+yz+%2Bzx%29+%3D+1) but maybe I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rahul was right; that looks like exactly the right kind of equation. Unfortunately, Wolfram seems to be plotting it in a very unhelpful orientation. Check out [grapher.mathpix.com](http://grapher.mathpix.com) for three-dimensional graphs you can actually control. Here's Rahul's equation with $a=5$, plotted along with the $xy$-, $yz$-, and $xz$-planes so you can focus on the part of the graph in the first octant:

[image]